# Why is it good to avoid instruction branching where possible?

Tags: programming-languages, assembly, system, cpu

I've often read that it's bad from a perf perspective that branching, kind of at an assembly instruction level, is bad. But I haven't really seen why it's so. So, why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most modern processors [prefetch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_prefetch) instructions and even [speculatively execute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) them before the code flow has reached that instruction. Having a branch means that there are suddenly two different instructions that might be the next instruction. There are at least three possible ways that this can interact with pre-fetching:

- Instructions after branches aren't pre-fetched. The [instruction pipeline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline) becomes empty and the processor must wait as the next instruction is fetched at the last moment, giving worse performance.
- The processor can *guess* which branch will be taken ([branch prediction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_prediction)) and prefetch and execute the appropriate instruction. If it guesses the wrong branch it will have to discard the work done though, and wait for the correct instruction to be fetched.
- The processor can fetch and execute *both* branches then discard the results from the branch that wasn't taken.

Depending on the processor and the specific code, the branch may or may not give significant performance impact compared to equivalent code without a branch. If the processor executing the code uses branch prediction (most do) and mostly guesses correctly for a specific piece of code it may not cause a significant performance impact. On the other hand if it mostly guess incorrectly it might give a huge slow down.

It can be hard to predict for a specific piece of code whether removing the branch will significantly speed up the code. When micro-optimizing it is best to measure the performance of both approaches rather than guess.

Answer (score 2):

It's bad because it interferes with [instruction prefetch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_prefetch). Modern processors can start to load the next command's bytes while still processing the first in order to run faster. When a branch occurs, that "next command" that was prefetched has to be thrown away, which wastes time. Inside of a tight loop or the like, those missed prefetches can add up.

Answer (score 1):

beacause the processor doesn't know what instructions it is supposed to prefetch for execution if you give it to possibilities. in the case that the branch goes the other way than expected it has to flush the instruction pipeline since those loaded instructions are wrong now and that makes it a couple cycles slower...

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the prefetch issues, if you're jumping, you're not doing other work...

Answer (score 1):

If you think about an automobile assembly line, you hear things like X number of cars come off the line in a day.  That doesnt mean the raw materials started at the beginning of the line and X number completed the whole run in a day.  Who knows it probably doesnt but could take a number of days per car beginning to end, thats the point of the assembly line.  Imagine though if for some reason you had a manufacturing change and you basically had to flush all the cars in the line and scrap them or salvage their parts to be put on another car at some other time.  It would take a while to fill that assembly line up and get back to X number of cars per day.

The instruction pipeline in a processor works exactly the same way, there arent hundreds of steps in the pipeline, but the concept is the same, to maintain that one or more instructions per clock cycle execution rate (X number of cars per day) you need to keep that pipeline running smoothly.  So you prefetch, that burns a memory cycle, which is usually slow but layers of caching helps.  Decode, takes another clock, execute, can take many clocks esp on a CISC like an x86.  When you perform a branch, on most processors, you have to throw away the instruction in the execute and prefetch, basically 2/3rds of your pipeline if you think in terms of a general, simplified pipeline.  Then you have to wait those clocks for the fetch, and decode before you get back into smooth execution.  On top of that the fetch, kinda by definition, not being the next instruction, some percentage of the time is more than a cacheline away and some percentage of the time that means a fetch from memory or a higher layer cache which is even more clock cycles than if you were executing linearly.  The other common solution is that some processors state that no matter what whatever instruction is after a branch instruction or sometimes two instruction after the branch instruction are always executed.  This way you execute as you flush the pipe, a good compiler will arrange the instructions so that something other a nop is after each branch.  The lazy way though is to just put a nop or two after every branch, creating another performance hit, but for that platform most folks will be used that.   A third way is what ARM does, having conditional execution.  For short, forward branches, which are not all that uncommon, instead of saying branch if condition, you mark the few instructions you are trying to branch over with execute if not condition, they go into decode and execute and execute as nops and the pipe keeps moving.  ARM relies on the traditional flush and refill for longer or backward branches.

Older x86 (the 8088/86) manuals as well as other equally old processor manuals for other processors as well as microcontroller manuals (new and old) will still publish the clock cycles for execution per instruction.  And for the branch instructions it will say add x number of clocks if the branch happens.  Your modern x86 and even ARM and other processors intended to run windows or linux or other (bulky and slow) operating systems dont bother, they often just say it runs one instruction per clock or talk about mips to megahertz or things like that and dont necessarily have a table of clocks per instruction.  You just assume one, and remember that is like one car per day, its that last execution clock not the other clocks getting there.  Microcontroller folks in particular deal with not one clock per instruction, and have to be more aware of execution times than the average desktop application.  Look at the specs for a few of them the Microchip PIC (not the PIC32, which is mips), the msp430, definitely the 8051, although those are or were made by so many different companies their timing specs vary wildly.

Bottom line, for desktop applications or even kernel drivers on an operating system, the compiler is not that efficient and the operating system adds that much more overhead that you will hardly notice the clock savings.  Switch to a microcontroller and put too many branches in and your code is up to 2 or 3 times slower.  Even with a compiler and not assembler.  Granted using a compiler (not writing in assembler) can/will make your code 2 to 3 times slower as well, you have to balance development, maintenance, and portability with performance.